# Random Dice Roll

Tags: java, random, dice

I'm kind of new to programming and I was wondering how I could write a java program for a random dice roll. The requirements for this is:

private members:
-final int numSides
^^The number of sides of the die
-public methods
^^Dice(int sides)
@@@Sets numSides to be the sides parameter.
@@@Used to create dice with varying number of sides, for example in main you could say Dice d6 = new Dice(6) to create a six-sided die.
^^int roll()
^^Returns a random integer from 1 up to and including numSides
NOTE: nextInt() from the Random class will return a value from zero up to the value passed in

So far I have

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Dice 
{
    private final int numSides;

    public Dice (int sides)
    {
        this.numSides = sides;

        Random dice = new Random();
        int num =0;
        int roll=0;

    }
     public int roll(int times)
     {
         int sum=0;
         for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
         {
             sum += roll();
         }

     }
     return sum;
}
```

I got this far from looking at some other examples, but I would like an explanation and help on how to finish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling to a `roll()` method, but you don't have it. I think you should write

```
public class Dice{
    private final int numSides;

    public Dice (int sides)
    {
        this.numSides = sides;

    }
    public int roll(int times)
    {
        int sum=0;
        Random dice = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
        {
            sum += dice.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
        }
        return sum;
    }

   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't answer if you think the linked question is a duplicate. If you don't think it is a duplicate, then you should explain the difference.  By the way, 6-sided dice don't have the numbers 0-5 on them.